# Дышать стало легче (?) и голоса под липами звучали мягче

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, авторская-пунктуация

Если голоса под липами звучали мягче вследствие того, что дышать стало легче, то запятая нужна, а если просто перечисляются два факта, второй из которых не является следствием первого, то запятая не нужна, что ли? Или наоборот?

Совсем запутался.
Про однородность комментарии вообще не понял.

**Прослушал "Lovers" (?) и зарыдал.**

Что ставить, когда причинно-следственная связь имеется/не имеется?

Answer (score 1):

**Тема 1.** Запятая в общем случае **ставится** между простыми предложениями в составе сложносочиненного предложения (ССП), но при этом мы должны быть уверены, что это ССП в двумя основами. Надо помнить, что предложения бывают двусоставными  (подлежащее + сказуемое) или односоставными (обычно одно сказуемое).

*Дышать стало легче, **и** голоса под липами звучали мягче.*  Это ССП, две грамматические основы, запятая  ставится.

**Тема 2**. Запятая не ставится **в частных случаях** при наличии **общего элемента и одиночного союза И, ИЛИ**. Чаще всего таким элементом является общий второстепенный член, но мы должны быть уверены, что он **действительно общий** для этих двух предложений:

***К вечеру** дышать стало легче  **и** голоса под липами звучали мягче.*

**Это самый спорный вопрос** в этой теме: как определить, что второстепенный член действительно общий?  В грамматике говорится, что **только однородные предложения можно соединить общим элементом,** но для этого надо знать признаки однородных предложений (такие предложения при отсутствии союза И произносят  с перечислительной интонацией).

Главное требование – это **независимость и равноправие предложений**, то есть отсутствие взаимообусловленных (причинно-следственных) отношений между ними. Реально события могут быть связаны, но  наблюдатель не знает об этом или просто не учитывает  такие связи. **Внешние признаки однородности**: события одновременные или следующие одно за другим (перечисление событий), одинаковый видо-временной план глаголов и т.д.

В частности это касается приведенного ССП. Если мы считаем простые предложения в составе ССП независимыми и просто  **перечисляем различные изменения**, то запятая при наличии союза И и общего обстоятельства не ставится.

Если поставить запятую, то мы как бы **подчеркиваем**, что между двумя событиями существует  **явная причинно-следственная связь** (а такая связь здесь явной не кажется, хотя какая-то взаимообусловленность, возможно, есть). Но у автора нет желания это обозначать, поэтому он изображает события **как независимые.**

**Тема 3**. Особые правила существуют для односоставных предложений вида: Прослушал "Lovers"  и зарыдал.  Эти предложения часто можно приравнять **однородным сказуемым**, а между однородными членами при наличии союза И запятая не ставится (им для отсутствия запятой общий второстепенный член не требуется, как в ССП).

Можно поставить интонационное тире:  *Прослушал "Lovers"  – и зарыдал.*

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133  Пункт 2, примечание.

Answer (score 0):

*Дышать стало легче, и голоса под липами звучали мягче.* «Следствия» ни при чём, а важно то, что это сложносочинённое предложение, то есть здесь два предложения в одном: два подлежащих, каждое со своим сказуемым. Короче говоря, запятая между двумя предложениями в одном — полагается.

*Прослушал "Lovers" и зарыдал.* А тут она не полагается, потому что вместо неё между однородными членами предложения (в данном случае это сказуемые, относящиеся к одному и тому же подлежащему) стоит союз ***и***.